# File cleared out after reopening it with std::fstream

Tags: c++, std, filestream, fstream

I want to open a file for reading, close it, and then open it again for writing using the same std::fstream. But when I reopen the file with writing permissions all the data inside is being cleared and it becomes 0 bytes long. 
Here's my code:

```
char* data = new char[5];
std::fstream fs("myFile", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);//opening with read
fs.read(data, 5);
fs.clear();
fs.close();
//Do some stuff
fs.open("myFile", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);//opening with write
//The file is already empty at this point
```

Comment: How do you check that the file is empty? Note that if you open file stream for write, the file contents is destroyed.

Comment: For that matter, how did you check the file is *filled* prior to the destructive call of the last line? Exactly *none* of the IO operations in this code are ever checked. Regardless, you seem to know the problem, *"But when I reopen the file with writing permissions all the data inside is being cleared"*, so is your *real* question "How do I open a file for write *without* destroying the existing content?"

Answer (score 3):

When opening a file with the default *write* flag, i.e., `std::ios::out` with the `<iostream>` facility or `"w"` with the `<cstdio>` functions, there is a combination of POSIX flags happening behind your back - a *truncate* flag is added. This means that upon opening in write mode, the file content is discarded. To circumvent this, open the file the second time with

```
fs.open("myFile", std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
```

The *append* mode moves the file cursor to the end of the file at each write operation and is not combined with the *truncate* flag, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open). Note that when you want to write to arbitrary positions in the existing file, you need to open it with

```
fs.open("myFile", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
```

which does not truncate its content and allows for cursor positioning with the `seek*` functions.

Comment: But if I open the file with ios::app then no matter where I write (at any offset) then the data will be appended to the end, and I don't want to do that. So how can I reopen the file without necessarily appending data to the end?

Comment: I came up with a solution, open the stream with both ios::in and ios::out. This is the only way to do it (as I understand from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)

Comment: Right, this is exactly as described in the post I linked. `ios::in | ios::out` are the default values for the concstructor of `std::fstream`. Maybe I should also put that in the answer.